# Unknown slow process of requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The behaviour is: the browser hangs keep loading without any response back.

Please see the following log.

```
I, [2014-07-16T14:14:09.766062 #11713]  INFO -- : Started GET "/somepage" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2014-07-16 14:14:09 +0800

I, [2014-07-16T14:14:40.872411 #31111]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy at 2014-07-16 14:14:40 +0800
I, [2014-07-16T14:14:40.874968 #31111]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#index as */*
I, [2014-07-16T14:14:40.893189 #31111]  INFO -- :   Rendered ...
I, [2014-07-16T14:14:40.901553 #31111]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 26ms (Views: 22.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)

... more other requests handled normally

I, [2014-07-16T14:29:35.395493 #11713]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#somepage as HTML
I, [2014-07-16T14:29:35.403614 #11713]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/somepage.html.erb (1.5ms)
I, [2014-07-16T14:29:35.403762 #11713]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 5.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

In between the "Started GET ..." and "Processing by" logs, the rails app can handle other requests normally. However, the 2 logs (should be from the same request) have around 15mins gap.

Server: Apache with passenger
Database: Mysql using mysql2 adapter

I completely lost and have no clues what is the root cause....

Comment: If you can reproduce this behavior in your system, inspect the actual traffic using tool like wireshark.

Comment: A long shot but if you happen to use NewRelic, their x-ray tool can be really useful to analyze requests in depth for a short period of time. I don't think it's part of the free plan though. :/

Answer (score 0):

I faced this similar kind of issue where the browser kept on loading with no logs in the log file.And what i found out was that we have mistakenly written `find.all` in **one of our model** as during testing it only had 1000 records as compared to production with more than 1 million records.so changing it to `batch records`/`pagination` resolved it.
...........Hope this might help you.